# Sound made in Ford Focus when plugged in

Tags: ford, battery, focus, jump-start

I had a dead battery this morning and plugged in my '03 Focus for the first time to charge up enough to get the dang thing out of the garage.  I was a little bit worried when I plugged it in because I heard a strange sound coming out of some place between the grill and the engine and I'm not sure what that was could anyone enlighten me?

The battery was dead to the point that the car wouldn't start, but the lights and radio still worked.

Comment: When you say you plugged in, you are saying that you have connected a battery charger to the battery?

Comment: It was plugged in to the wall via the electrical charger outlet thing.

Comment: First time I hear of an onboard electric charger.. Are you sure is not the block heater? And Ford did not made a Focus Hybrid in 2003.

Comment: Oh, maybe that's what it is!  ha, I guess it's just a coincidence that my car turned over after having it plugged in for 5 minutes?

Comment: So now, do the car start easily? Your battery should have recharge when the car was running(through the alternator).

Comment: yeah. [this](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/1526/fixing-a-trunk-latch-on-a-ford-focus) was the reason the battery died.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the comments described, you probably plugged in the block heater. Perhaps the heater warmed up the entire engine compartment over time, including the battery. Batteries deliver less current when cold, so it might have been just under the current required to turn the engine. Guess you'll find out if it starts again tomorrow!