# How to access negative battery terminal in 04 Pontiac Montana

Tags: battery, pontiac, jump-start

So my hand is all scuffed up from trying to get to the (-) terminal for jumper cables to jump my [Ford Focus with the defective trunk latch which apparently has been draining my battery](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/1526/fixing-a-trunk-latch-on-a-ford-focus).  The fuse box is right on top of the battery giving you access to only the positive terminal.

This seems to me to be a lesson in the tragedy of the commons, but seriously, how do I get to the negative terminal to provide enough juice to jump my car?

Answer (score 2):

[Check this answer](http://www.fixya.com/cars/t10669290-need_jump_start_our_second_vehicle_using), looks they have a remote negative near the shock mount. Check the owners manual, you may find more details on this.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, I must gut my [car](http://www.fixya.com/cars/t7482370-location_negative_terminal_battery) in order to jump another car - hopefully I never meet anyone without a socket wrench set who needs a jump in the middle of nowhere.

To paraphrase fixya.com,

1. pop off the wiper cover
2. Unscrew the fusebox bolt
3. Remove the big bar going over the fuseboxes

and **3.** was where my wife appeared and said, "stop ripping apart my minivan you can take it to work tomorrow."

Comment: I probably would have considered finding a good metal surface somewhere near a ground strap to try.  You're supposed to do that on the receiving vehicle anyways.  Might be a little less efficient on the sending vehicle too, but I can't think of any major problems you'd be likely to have.  The jumper cables usually can't handle as much current as a ground strap anyways.  I guess it could cause a damage if you already had a bad grounding problem with the car though, but there's that risk no matter how you do a jumpstart.